# Sympy TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational when dumping to YAML

Tags: python, yaml, sympy, pyyaml

I'm getting this error when trying to dump a sympy expression to YAML:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

What I am trying to dump is a set with 2 `sympy.Symbol` objects. I'm not sure why sympy tries to evaluate it as a `StrictLessThan` object. sympy is trying to determine the truth value, perhaps to evaluate the `mapping.sort()` function?

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Matt/Documents/ProgrammingProjects/infinitree/abg.py", line 267, in <module>
    print yaml.dump(mtree)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 202, in dump
    return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=Dumper, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\__init__.py", line 190, in dump_all
    dumper.represent(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 28, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 61, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 434, in represent_object
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 61, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 434, in represent_object
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 223, in represent_dict
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 61, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 434, in represent_object
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 61, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 434, in represent_object
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 223, in represent_dict
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 223, in represent_dict
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 61, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 434, in represent_object
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 123, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 57, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 229, in represent_set
    return self.represent_mapping(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:set', value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 120, in represent_mapping
    mapping.sort()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Answer (score 2):

The representer tries to sort the set, which is dumped in a similar way as a dict, by sorting its items by key-value pairs and then dumping those. I don't know the details of `sympy`, but for the sorting a representation of the key and value need be knows (for a set only the key is used) and that is often done using the string representation, which, I guess, causes the evaluation. So the `mapping.sort()` evaluates the `sympy` objects it uses as keys, not the other way around (as you indicated in your question might have been the case)

However it is not just the sorting that is the problem, `sympy` objects cannot be dumped without additional representer routines:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from sympy.abc import x, y
from  sympy.core.relational import Relational

data = Relational(y, x+x**2, '==')

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which errors as well:

```
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: Eq(y, x**2 + x)
```

So I would start simple, by making representers for your the object types you use and want to dump and then collections of those should be dumpable as well.

---

<sub>I used my ruamel.yaml library instead of the outdated PyYAML that only supports the YAML 1.1 specifications. Both should behave in the same way with regards to this issue.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll give it a shot tomorrow

Comment: There are examples representers here on [so] and in the ruamel.yaml/PyYAML docs. If that doesn't suffice you know where to ask, but make sure to include some minimal example code (that makes helping much easier).

Comment: Hi @Anton, thanks for the suggestions, I really appreciate it. I didn't include a lot of code in the post since I had subclassed some of the classes I'm trying to dump, and I didn't want to post so much that someone who is willing to help would be overwhelmed. If there is anything else that you think I should include in the post that would help you and others understand the context better, please let me know. I guess In my attempt to concise I may have cut out too much.

Comment: @Matt Unless someone did **exactly** what you did, the error message doesn't help much to determine what might have happened. For me that is not enough to reproduce things. So I just tried (never done before) to dump some `sympy` stuff. I prefer to get a question with some code: a minimal example that throws the error. And making such a minimal example can be an effort, but it might help you to localize the cause, or find (as I suspect here), that yours is some follow up error.

Comment: I don't know about yaml dumpers, but the best way to roundtrip a SymPy expression is to use `srepr()` and `sympify()`.